# Get rid of just the UPPER form of a word in SQL

Tags: sql, sybase

I want to get rid of a specific word that exists in an UPPER and Capitalize manner. E.g the word is CONDIMENTS and Condiments. It exists in both ways and I want the first( i.e "CONDIMENTS") to be deleted. If I use `case when X IN('CONDIMENTS') then NULL`, both values disappear. Any ideas?

The  RDBMS is sybase SQL Anywhere

Essentially I want to make my IN operator case sensitive. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Show us some sample data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) I.e. [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember it clearly -- as I used ASA 12 about 3 years before and got the similar issue as yours...Here's what I can remember --
ASA instance can't change the property of "case sensitive" after creation -- there's a parameter "case [respect|ignore]" only in "create database" command and after the DB was created -- this option can't be changed otherwise the index especially the index over string columns would be corrupted.
So you can only check this DB property with
`select db_property('CaseSensitive')` -- if it's OFF then your DB was created as no case sensitive.
If you really need your DB case sensitive -- you have to recreate this ASA db and export/import data from your original db...